# IndexArray out of range with default number of collectionviewcells

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am struggling with this code.

```
if facebookPhotos.count != 0 {         
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookPhotos[indexPath.row]) {    
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = image
    }
}
```

I have an array of facebookphotos and an UICollectionView => returns 6 cells by default.

When I try to load photos into it (lets say 3) it crashes. How can i make 6 Cells appear, but only those filled, which are having an equivalent photo at indexPath.row ?

It is important to have these 6 Cells though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple to avoid index array out of range exception: all you need to do is comparing `facebookPhotos.count` to `indexPath.row`:

```
if facebookPhotos.count < indexPath.row {         
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookPhotos[indexPath.row]) {    
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = image
    }
} else {
    // Clear out the image on a recycled cell
    collectionCell.collectionViewImage = nil
}
```

Comment: Made my Day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason I am again getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: @jvs it is either coming from a different place in code, or there is a thread that concurrently modifies your array.